# Помогите переписать код с jQuery на чистый JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть код для выпадающего меню, но он на jQuery, попытался переписать сам, но что-то не работает

Код jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $toggleButton = $('.toggle-button'),
        $menuWrap = $('.menu-wrap');
    $toggleButton.on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-open');
        $menuWrap.toggleClass('menu-show');
    });
});
```

Мои попытки:

```
function buttonClick() {
    const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
    const menuWrap = document.querySelector('.menu-wrap');

    toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.classList.toggle('button-open');
        menuWrap.classList.toggle('menu-show')
    });
}
```

HTML и CSS:

```
<span onclick="buttonClick()" class="toggle-button">
     <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-top"></div>
     <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-middle"></div>
     <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>
</span>

<div class="menu-wrap">
     <div class="menu-sidebar">
           <ul class="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
</div>

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 44px;
    height: 40px;
    transition: .25s;
    z-index: 15;
}
.toggle-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 80%;
    transition: .5s;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-top {
    border: 4px solid #555;
    border-bottom: none;
    top: 0;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-middle {
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #555;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    top: 4px;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-bottom {
    border: 4px solid #555;
    border-top: none;
    top: 22px;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-top {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 8px);
    transition: .5s;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-middle {
    transform: translate(230px);
    transition: .1s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -7px);
    transition: .5s;
}

.menu-wrap {
    display: none;
    background-color: #8B0000;
    opacity: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 950px;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: .25s;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.menu-show {
    margin-left: 0;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 15px 1px #B9ADAD;
}
```

Comment: Стрелочная функция this не передаёт
Используйте function()

Comment: Вывел в функцию, указал на теге span onlick="buttonClick()", но почему то все равно не работает(

Comment: Пофиксил, спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
const menuWrap = document.querySelector('.menu-wrap');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  ev.target.classList.toggle('button-open');
  menuWrap.classList.toggle('menu-show');
});
```

```css
.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  z-index: 15;
}
.toggle-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 80%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-top {
  border: 4px solid #555;
  border-bottom: none;
  top: 0;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-middle {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #555;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  top: 4px;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-bottom {
  border: 4px solid #555;
  border-top: none;
  top: 22px;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-top {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 8px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-middle {
  transform: translate(230px);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -7px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-wrap {
  display: none;
  background-color: #8b0000;
  opacity: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 950px;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: 0.25s;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu-show {
  margin-left: 0;
  box-shadow: 4px 2px 15px 1px #b9adad;
}
```

```html
<span class="toggle-button">
      <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-top"></div>
      <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-middle"></div>
      <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>
    </span>

    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <div class="menu-sidebar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: В принципе, я был близок, но почему то на страничке все равно не выполняется(, хотя на SO, нажимаю "Выполнить код", и оно почему то работает :/

Comment: Пофиксил, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: отметьте как решение)